# cloudfoundry quotas: disk usage, instances, private domains

Tags: cloud-foundry, paas

Is there a possibility to set a maximum on disk usage, number of application instances or number of private domains on organization or space level in cloudfoundry? The command line interface only supports

```
-i instance memory
-m total memory
-s number of services
-r number of routes
```

Seems like also the REST api only supports these options. 
Is there any plan to add the above mentioned additional attributes to space or organization quotas?

Answer (score 0):

There are plans to limit app instances and private domains via quotas.

https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/83375624
https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/83375642
https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/92102714